# Get logs for specific date (apache access log)

Tags: linux, bash

Can you on advice me on how to get specific time range  from a file with output like:

```
81.200.176.13 - - [23/Mar/2021:09:34:03 +0000] "GET /crx/packmgr/img/thumbnail.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6235
```

I need to date from 22 march 20 to 22 o'clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your time range is very specific, you might just use `grep`:

```
grep '\[23/Mar/2021:2[0-2]' /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

I.e. search for the date string and than in the range of 20-22h

Alternatively and for future reference, `sed` might be the way to go:

```
sed `/START/,/END/p`
```

e.g.

```
sed '/21\/Mar\/2021:01:/,/23\/Mar\/2021:22:/p'
```

If you force apache to use `journald` ([ref](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_journald.html) - note the warning there), one might in future even rely on:

```
journald -u apache2 --since "2021-03-23 20:00:00" --until "2021-03-23 22:00:00"
```

Comment: op specified 22 march but you've used 23 march in your answer/regex. This might confuse op.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you open the log file in a text editor, and then search for the earliest timestamp and then go from there? If you want to make it real simple.

In VIM, while you are not in editing mode, you can write /2021:20 , it will jump to the first line that includes this timestamp. Scroll from there.

Comment: Use `view` or `vim -R` for read-only.